# Convert table with date range into list of dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called dateRange which looks like this

```
|ID|dateStart|  dateEnd|
| 1|14-May-14|16-May-14|
| 1|20-May-14|21-May-14|
| 2|20-May-14|21-May-14|
```

Which I would like to convert to the following format in a table called dateListed

```
|ID|     date|
| 1|14-May-14|
| 1|15-May-14|
| 1|16-May-14|
| 1|20-May-14|
| 1|21-May-14|
| 2|20-May-14|
| 2|21-May-14|
```

I have reviewed the following question, [Convert Date Range to Individual Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151733/convert-date-range-to-individual-days), however, as the data is slightly different I was hoping someone could assist me?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did this table come from?

Comment: @Strawberry are you referring to the dateRange table?  If so, it's just a list of dates that I have in excel that I have imported into a table.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223032/mysql-display-all-date-in-between-range and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range found as top 2 results of Google search terms "mysql list of dates from date range".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a utility table of dates, then it's easy...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID INT NOT NULL 
,dateStart date NOT NULL
,dateEnd date NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(ID,dateStart)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2014-05-14','2014-05-16'),
(1,'2014-05-20','2014-05-21'),
(2,'2014-05-20','2014-05-21');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------------+------------+
| ID | dateStart  | dateEnd    |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2014-05-14 | 2014-05-16 |
|  1 | 2014-05-20 | 2014-05-21 |
|  2 | 2014-05-20 | 2014-05-21 |
+----+------------+------------+

SELECT x.ID
     , c.dt date 
  FROM calendar c 
  JOIN my_table x 
    ON c.dt BETWEEN x.dateStart AND x.dateEnd 
 ORDER  
    BY ID
     , date;
+----+------------+
| ID | date       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2014-05-14 |
|  1 | 2014-05-15 |
|  1 | 2014-05-16 |
|  1 | 2014-05-20 |
|  1 | 2014-05-21 |
|  2 | 2014-05-20 |
|  2 | 2014-05-21 |
+----+------------+
```