# SSIS Merge While?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have two datasets. One is a dimension table with data similar to the below sample

```
Table1

Key    StartDate     EndDate       Name       Data_1
1      2017-01-01    2017-01-03    Billy G    58uf
2      2017-01-10    2017-01-12    S Dogg     4940
```

I also have a standard Date Dimension called dbo.DimDate. How can I Merge the date dimension onto the Table1 so that Table1 contains a record for each day between StartDate and EndDate for each record?

The desired result is something like this:

```
Table2 

Key    StartDate     EndDate       Name       Data_1    Day
1      2017-01-01    2017-01-03    Billy G    58uf      2017-01-01
1      2017-01-01    2017-01-03    Billy G    58uf      2017-01-02
1      2017-01-01    2017-01-03    Billy G    58uf      2017-01-03
2      2017-01-10    2017-01-12    S Dogg     4940      2017-01-10
2      2017-01-10    2017-01-12    S Dogg     4940      2017-01-11
2      2017-01-10    2017-01-12    S Dogg     4940      2017-01-12
```

This needs to be accomplished in an SSIS package. I don't think a simple MERGE JOIN will work because 1) The Date dimension does not have a key that matches anything in Table1, and 2) I need it to add a Day for every date BETWEEN StartDate and EndDate

If I do an execute SQL Command, then how do I get it to pull from two separate tables?

Comment: the last record from your desired result, why the `EndDate` is '2017-01-11' not '2017-01-12'?

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: If there is no common column (or key) to join, cannot use `Merge Join`, I will think about an alternate way to do this

Comment: can you show what does DimDate table look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a simple OLE DB source which executed the SQL command I copied from another post on stackoverflow ( seen here: [SQL query to convert date ranges to per day records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363003/sql-query-to-convert-date-ranges-to-per-day-records))

Basically just copied that, adjusted table names, and then pasted in the Source properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Lookup.   Your main source component will be the date dimension, and in the lookup, you'll get the row of Table1 where the date dimension's date is in the start/end range, and add those columns to your dataflow.